# Else if, URL redirection

Tags: javascript, url, if-statement

So I am using this current script below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.location.href.indexOf('thevault') > -1) {

//window.location = 'http://thevault.co.uk/index.phtml?d=512060’;
window.location = '/index.phtml?d=512060';

} else {

//window.location = 'http://www.jths.co.uk/index.phtml?d=541300';
window.location = '/index.phtml?d=541300';

}
</script>
```

Which works fine, however I want to add another condition

if the url is:  http://www.nationalforestteachingschool.co.uk , then go to this page:

https://thevault.jths.co.uk/index.phtml?d=550968

I have tried the else if command but can't seem to get it working, this needs to be in one continous script, any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

I made this small script to avoid having too many if / else statements, basically you define all your checks and redirects in the beginning and then let the script loop through them:

http://jsfiddle.net/XYaFg/1/

```
var Redirects = function(currentUrl) {

    var urls = [
    {
        check : 'thevault',
        redirect : 'http://thevault.co.uk/index.phtml?d=512060'
    },

    {
        check : 'fiddle',
        redirect : 'http://another-url-to-redirect-to.html'
    },

    {
        check : 'last-url-check',
        redirect : 'http://some-more-redirect.html'
    },
];

    this.init = function() {
        var length = urls.length;

        for ( var i = 0 ; i < length ; i++) {
            var current = urls[i];
            if( currentUrl.indexOf(current.check) > -1) {
                alert("Redirecting to " + current.redirect);
                //window.location = current.redirect
            }
        }
    }
    this.init();
}

var redirects = new Redirects(window.location.href)
```

You have to uncomment the "window.location" row and comment out the "alert" stuff

Comment: Hi and thanks for this.......... just now trying to get this sorted again, would the following work?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [W3Schools site](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp).

> If...else if...else Statement

```
if (condition1)
{
  code to be executed if condition1 is true
}
else if (condition2)
{
  code to be executed if condition2 is true
}
else
{
  code to be executed if neither condition1 nor condition2 is true
}
```

You can chain many `else if` blocks if you need to..

Consider using the [Switch statement](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) as well.

Comment: Hi MaxS, Looked at this site with the else if, but could not get it working, problem is on our school server we only have one IP address hence the need for the script, but as we are expanding we are needing to build more site for external use......