# Redirection for 3 sites

Tags: redirect

Does anyone know if the following code will work, we have 3 sites to be accessed from one IP address, currently 2 are being used and a script for them works (The Vault & jths.co.uk) but a third site has been built so some more redirection needs to take place.....

Thoughts?

```
var Redirects = function(currentUrl) {

    var urls = [
    {
        check : 'thevault',
        redirect : 'http://thevault.co.uk/index.phtml?d=512060'
    },

    {
        check : 'jths',
        redirect : 'http://jths.co.uk/index.phtml?d=541300'
    },

    {
        check : 'nationalforestteachingschool',
        redirect : 'http://jths.co.uk/index.phtml?d=550968&preview=1&t=1371981393'
    },
];

    this.init = function() {
        var length = urls.length;

        for ( var i = 0 ; i < length ; i++) {
            var current = urls[i];
            if( currentUrl.indexOf(current.check) > -1) {
                alert("Redirecting to " + current.redirect);
                //window.location = current.redirect
            }
        }
    }
    this.init();
}

var redirects = new Redirects(window.location.href)
```

Comment: "Does anyone know if the following code will work" looks like you haven't even tried the code yet.

Comment: He copy/pasted it from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528707/else-if-url-redirection/17529096?noredirect=1#comment28147847_17529096

Comment: would rather know before hand as will have to shut down our school website and VLE

Comment: yes I did, but wanted to check with people who probably knew more than me first...

Comment: so this was unsuccessful